# ARM template validation failed

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I tried various regions still same problem, **here the error message :**

> Error Message :  Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template
>   deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id:
>   '/subscriptions/----------------------/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ARM_VM-001'
>
> failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource
>   '/subscriptions/--------------/resourceGroups/AzureResourceGroup1-2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ARM_VM-001'
>   is currently not available in location 'westus' zones '' for
>   subscription '-----------'.
>
> Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones.
>   See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'.

The deployment validation failed

Comment: Try changing the VM size

Answer (score 0):

Since not all SKU are available in all regions in Azure, you can use CLI to figure out whether the SKU you are looking for is available or not.

```
az vm list-skus --location <region> --query "[].{name:name}" -o table
```

You can use the above Azure CLI command to determine if the VM Size you are looking for is available in the given region (westus in your case).

you can provide the Size also and get a more narrowed down result as well

```
az vm list-skus --location <region> --size Standard_ --query "[].{name:name}" -o table
```

the above will provide all the Standard sizes avaliable in

if you want to find if a specific size is available in a specific region, try the below command

```
az vm list-skus --location southcentralus --size Standard_DS14-8_v2 --output table
```

This link > [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest] has list of CLI commands you can execute for operations relating to VMs

Hope this helps.